# How to implement pagination on multiple table on same page in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm working on project in an asp.Net mvc4 in which requirement is very complex. I'm using ADO.Net for performing database operation. i have three models which have relation. against one items there is multiple organization and in organization there is multiple department. multiple and that items is belong to that organization and department. I need to show that department in multiple nested tables against that every organization against that item and have to perform pagination on each tables. How will I perform all these operations?

1. how will I write a query in database to that give me multiple organization, and multiple department in every organization against that item. how i will populate the model with that data?
2. how can I show on the page and perform pagination on each table?

Comment: Your question is too broad, most likely you will not get any answers to that. I suggest you narrow down your question(s) and show us what have you done so far (i.e: the DB related part: what are the tables, relations between them, what did you write as the sql query, what is the result of that and what do you expect?).

Comment: @qqbenq i done db part now want to show on the page and perform pagination  one item belong to an organization and department. each organization has may department and that item can be in many department and organization.

Comment: there becomes multiple table item if items belong to multiple department. and need to perform pagination on each table.